# Nodejs Passport Local Strategy always failing

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I am new to the whole user authentication things with node and I am trying to learn how to use Passport's LocalStrategy to add users to a Mongo database.

I'm trying to follow a particular tutorial and for some reason things aren't going to plan. Whenever I submit the registration form the strategy always fails (is redirected to the failure page). I have a feeling it is something to do with the body of he request not being passed (since the log I placed in where the strategy is declared is not run). However it seems like the current infrastructure makes it hard to refactor. Can this code be refactored such that the request can be parsed manually (e.g. request.body.* name *) before handing it over to passport?

Unless the issue is something completely different, in which case I have no idea...

index.js:

```
// Use middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(expressSession({ secret: 'whatkindofgamedoyouthinkthisishey',
                    cookie: {maxAge:null},
                    resave: false,
                    saveUninitialized: false}));
require("./config/passport")(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

// Obtain application modules
var userModels = require("./schemas/user")(mongoose);
var loginPage = require("./routes/login")(passport, userModels);

// Initialize Routes
app.use("/", loginPage);
```

passport.js (should come up with a better name):

```
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy,
    User = require("../schemas/user");

module.exports = function (passport) {
     passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
     done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use("local-signup", new LocalStrategy({
        email: "email",
        password: "password",
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function (request, email, password, done) {
        console.log("message sent to sign up"); // log not running
        process.nextTick(function () {
            User.findOne({email: email}, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, request.flash("signupMessage", "That email is already taken"));
                } else {
                    var newUser = new User();
                    newUser.email = email;
                    newUser.password = password;

                    newUser.save(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        } else {
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
));
};
```

login.js (router being exported)

```
router.post("/register", passport.authenticate("local-signup", {
    successRedirect: "/loggedIn",
    failureRedirect: "/connectFailed",
    failureFlash: false
}));
```

Html form:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="/register" method="POST">
    <div class="logoContainer">
        <img src="images/LogoWithoutText.png" class="image image-responsive" id="loginImage">
    </div>
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try with action=''/routes/login/register" in the html form tag.

Comment: I've tested the router is configured with a "non-passport" route, and it works fine. So that is not the issue (tried your solution and it didn't work).

Answer (score -1):

From what I can read in the passportjs.org/docs, it looks like passport.use has the following signature:

```
var passport = require('passport'), 
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
   email: "email",
   password: "password",
   passReqToCallback: true
},
function(req, email, password, done) {
 User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
   if (err) { return done(err); }
   if (!user) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
   }
   if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
   }
   return done(null, user);
  });
 }
));
```

So, try changing the way passport.use is written and try you luck.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding something, but to me this looks the same, just without the process.nextTick(), and I pass passport in when requiring the module. I'm not sure what changes to make.